# accessing a positional parameter through a variable

Tags: bash, shell, positional-parameter

I'm trying to access a positional parameter using a variable.

i.e. if I define a variable as 1, I want to access the 1st positional parameter, if I define it as 2 I want to access the 2nd positional parameter.

example: 
bash script.bash arg1 arg2 arg3

```
 var=2
 echo $var // will only echo no. 2
 ??? // insert your command to echo the 2nd positional parameter (arg2)
```

can this be done?

Comment: Yes! thanks. But just to make it easier for other readers - you access it like this: ${!var}, i.e. ehco ${!var} will echo arg2

Comment: But that solution will make the script less portable, see the comments that follow my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
[[ "$var" -eq "1" ]] && echo "$1" #for positional parameter 1
```

and so on or you could do it like below :

```
#!/bin/sh
var=2
eval echo "\$${var}" # This will display the second positional parameter an so on
```

**Edit**

> how do I use this if I actually need to access outside of echo. for
>   example "if [ -f \$${var} ]"

The method you've pointed out it the best way:

```
var=2 
eval temp="\$${var}"
if [ -f "$temp" ] # Do double quote
then
#do something
fi
```

Comment: Uh, that's not very scalable in the general case.

Comment: Bash has `${!var}` to avoid using eval

Comment: @tripleee : Please see the update.

Comment: @123 : Valid point, but that would make the solution bash specific,. For example `dash` doesn't support `${!var}`

Comment: Question is tagged bash.

Comment: @123 : Question is tagged `shell` too. My solution works at the least on bash, dash, ksh,

Comment: I added the [tag:bash] tag because the OP had that in their example, but I'm a bit hesitant.

Comment: I use bash. In any case - how do I use this if I actually need to access outside of echo. for example "if [ -f \$${var} ]" ?

Comment: ok, I got it - you declare the variable in advance. I.e. var=2  eval var2="\$${var}" .

Comment: Nice, thanks for the note on portability.